# Chrome extension to toggle tabs: issue with tab selection timeout

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a simple extension that toggles between the current and the last focused tab. Toggling can be either done by `ALT+Q` or by clicking on the button in the extension icon bar. There is just one problem. The extension seems to forget about the last focused tab after a certain time spent on the current tab. That is, I cannot toggle back to the last focused tab anymore.

Can anyone please give me an explanation why my extension forgets about the last focused tab?

```
// manifest.json

{    
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "name": "Toggle Switch Recent Last Tabs",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Toggle between your current and last used (focused) tab with a keyboard shortcut (ALT+Q by default) or mouse click on the icon.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "commands": {
        "toggle": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+Q"
            },
            "description": "Toggle tabs"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon_16.png",
        "32": "icon_32.png",
        "48": "icon_48.png",
        "128": "icon_48.png"
    }
}
```

And `background.js`:

```
// background.js

var previousTab;
var currentTab;

// General functions
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(previousTab, {selected: true});
});

chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (previousTab == null) {
        previousTab = tab;
    }
    if (currentTab == null) {
        currentTab = tab;
    }
    else {
        previousTab = currentTab;
        currentTab = tab;
    }
});


// Keyboard shortcut toggle function
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "toggle") {

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        previousTab = tab.id;
        currentTab = null;
    });

    chrome.tabs.update(previousTab, {selected: true});
  }
});
```

[Download in Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-switch-recent-last/odhjcgnlbagjllfbilicalpigimhdcll)

[Complete source code](https://github.com/orschiro/Toggle-Switch-Recent-Last-Tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you are loosing state.  May be because your background page is not persistent (`persistent: false` in manifest.json).

This kind of page is called [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), instead of background page, and for efficiency it unloads after few seconds of inactivity and reload when a event call it.

It's weird, I have to explain: first of all Chrome run this page only to register listeners.  After that, the page is unloaded, loosing global variables, but Chrome remember the listeners.  When a event call one of them, Chrome loads the whole Event page, global variables are created again with their initial value.

To fix it, first of all try to change `persistent` to `true`.  If it works, it's best to go back to `persistent: false` and save your variables (previousTab, currentTab) in storage.

[`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) is faster and more efficient, but asynchronous.  It worth spending some minutes to make it work!